# pthread mutex_init returned error 95

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am trying to initialize the pthread_mutex_init with attribute my_attr.

```
int settype_retValue=pthread_mutexattr_settype( &my_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

cout << " settype_retValue =0" << settype_retValue << endl;
int nRet = pthread_mutex_init(&blist_mutex, &my_attr);
if( nRet )
    cout << " mutex_init returned " << nRet << endl;
else
    cout << " mutex_init has initilised without any error\n;
```

After compiling above set of code I am getting error as below and it is hanging over there.

OUTPUT::==>
settype_retValue =0
mutex_init returned 95

Can anyone please help to understand why I am getting return value for 95.
What is significance of 95.

I know that if mutex_init fails it gives one of the following error::

1. EINVAL The attribute set is not initialized
2. EINVAL The specified protocol is invalid
3. EAGAIN The system lacked the necessary resources to initialize another mutex.
4. ENOMEM Insufficient memory exists to initialize the mutex.
5. EBUSY Attempted to reinialize the object reference

May know 95 refers to which one of the above or 95 means something other.

And also how to do GDB debugging to go into the phterad library.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are blist_mutex and settype_retValue defined ?

Comment: On Linux, 95 is "EOPNOTSUPP" (not supported). Have you initialised `my_attr` correctly?

Comment: Check the definitions of blist_mutex and settype_retValue.

Comment: Have you compiled with the **-pthread** option ?

Comment: You can let it give you a string for the error code with `strerror(nRet)`, and for 95 I believe it is "Operation not supported". I think you have to use `pthread_mutexattr_init()` for `my_attr` first.

Comment: Hi @jens ..I got it..I am getting "Operation not supported" error in initilizing mutex....Can you please help to know Do I have to use pthread_mutexattr_init() for my_attr before pthread_mutex_init and why ?

Comment: Hi @jens pthread_mutexattr_init() has solved my issue...What is difference if I use pthread_mutexattr_init() and if I do not use pthread_mutexattr_init() on pthread_mutex_init()...Thanks in advance

Comment: You just have to initialize the attribute you are using before you use it - and appearantly the pthread_mutex_init() makes use of your attribute already.